# Unable to locate Spring Namespace for JAX-WS

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

I want to integrate JAX-WS to my Spring project. Found this link:
http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/

I adopted it and integrated it to my *applicationContext.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" 
   xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cloud" />
    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <wss:binding url="/notification" service="#notificationService"></wss:binding>  
    <ws:service id="notificationService" bean="#notificationImpl"></ws:service> 

    <bean id="notificationImpl" class="cloud.balancer.Notification" /> 
</beans>
```

But every time I start Tomcat, I get this exception:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`
>       `org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException`: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [`http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet`]
>       Offending resource: ServletContext resource [`/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`]

Eclipse does not report any errors about the namespace. I found a few similar problems with google, but none fixed my error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just a hunch - try adding [this](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/spring/jaxws-spring/1.8/jaxws-spring-1.8.jar) dependency to your classpath.

Comment: Ya, you are missing the JAR that this code is in.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The lib was missing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Tried adding the jar: jaxws-spring-1.8.xsd from http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/spring/jaxws-spring/ but still getting the same error on the spring context

Answer (score 6):

Same problem in this : [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-httpjax-ws-dev-java-netspringservlet/) , you need jaxws-spring.jar from - http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/spring/jaxws-spring/